# Read certain child elements from specific parent element

Tags: xml, vb.net, parent-child

Example XML;

```
<root>
 <cmdset>Set 1
     <comment>Comment 1 here.</comment>
     <cmd>Command 1</cmd>
     <cmd>Command 2</cmd>
 </cmdset>

 <cmdset>Set 2
     <comment>Comment 2 here.</comment>
     <cmd>Command 3</cmd>
     <cmd>Command 4</cmd>
 </cmdset>
</root>
```

Currently I have a listbox which populates the `<cmdset>` elements. Code is;

```
    Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
    doc.Load("help.xml")
    For Each textNode As XmlText In doc.SelectNodes("//cmdset/text()")
        listCmdSet.Items.Add(textNode.InnerText)
    Next
```

Which outputs to the listbox;

```
Set 1
Set 2
```

I now want to be able to process certain child elements within a particular `<cmdset>` element, only the `<cmd>` elements in this example, not the `<comment>` element. So if Set 1 is selected in the listbox, I only want to process the text "Command 1" and "Command 2".

I have been advised that giving the elements an ID or a name would make things easier but I would like to avoid this where possible as I intend the XML to be editable by end users (sometimes not very technical) so am trying to keep things simple as possible.

I have tried various different ideas I had but to no avail, I am new to XML (got the code to populate the listbox from SO) so if anything I have done so far is bad practice, please shout up.

Comment: So you want it to use `text() = "Set 1` to be the condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it would be easier to do that if the value you were looking at was in an attribute or a child element, but it's still possible to do it.  This will loop through all of the `cmd` values for the `cmdset` that contains the text `Set 1`:

```vb
For Each node As XmlNode In doc.SelectNodes("//cmdset[normalize-space(text())='Set 1']/cmd")
    Dim value As String = node.InnerText
    ' ...
Next
```

The square brackets establish a condition, so only elements where that condition is true will be included.  The `normalize-space` function is necessary to essentially trim the text to get rid of the new-line after the text.

It's a little unclear, though, from your question, if that's exactly what you are asking.  If you already have a reference to the desired parent element, then you can simply do this:

```vb
Dim cmdsetElement As XmlElement = ' ...
For Each node As XmlNode in cmdsetElement.SelectNodes("cmd")
    Dim value As String = node.InnerText
    ' ...
Next
```

Comment: All sorted now, thanks. You are becoming a familiar face on here. I think you have answered my last 2 or 3 questions now. Thanks!